# summernote text not storing into database

Tags: php, summernote

I am using summernote for editing the text , when I give the style to text by summernote toolbar or menu, it appears, but after submitting the text and html tags are stored in database, the style escaping by this.

```
<div id="summernote"><?php echo stripslashes($career['description']); ?></div>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="deschere" name="desc" placeholder="Description" rows="20" style="display: none;"></textarea>
```

script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#thisform').submit(function(e){
    $('#deschere').html($('#summernote').code());
    console.log($('#deschere').html());
    //e.preventDefault();
});
```

code to store in database

```
$data['title']= $this->input->post('title');
$data['description']= $this->input->post('desc');
$data['date']=date('Y/m/d h:i');
$id=$this->input->post('id');
$this->db->where('id',$id);
$response=$this->db->update('careers',$data);
return $response;
```

anyone have solution for this ?
 thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Check XSS Filtering in application/config/config.php
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE; set to FALSE; because it will remove inline style from summernote.

2. $this->input->post('desc', FALSE); set to FALSE

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps when you insert data into the database , the tags are automatically removed?

Comment: so what should i do ?, i use var_dump() on controller, still there was no css  to text

Comment: What kind of framework do You use? Seems like CodeIgniter, right? In database is everything ok? Column description contains html tags etc?